# android dynamically add checkbox Compilation error

Tags: android, dynamic, checkbox

i was wondering what i am doing wrong as my app won't compile.
The setonCheckedChangeListener(this); asks for a cast.
I am trying to add checkboxes from content separated by a ", " ( the content is downloaded through JSON)

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {
int array_Count=0;
// The next part is in the onCreate method, after the data has been pulled out of my intent.
String[] seperatedString = list.split(", ");
Array_Count=seperatedString.length;

    LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_label);

    for (int i = 0; i < Array_Count; i++) 
    {
        TableRow row =new TableRow(this);
        row.setId(i);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setText(seperatedString[i]);
        row.addView(checkBox);  
        my_layout.addView(row);
    }
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SingleContactActivity` should implement [`OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) interface.

```
public class SingleContactActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
```